# how to post data from custom template to google forms

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-drive-api, google-forms, contact-form

how to send contact us form data from my website to google forms. I have created a google form

> https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSedlnzPGGIwjq_C3W0KCev-WexWs6SF-df7nk0sWT3v2wP6fA/viewform

and took the name of the form data and copied action from the google form and pasted in my contact us website form. When submit the details I am getting following errors:

1. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSedlnzPGGIwjq_C3W0KCev-WexWs6SF-df7nk0sWT3v2wP6fA/formResponse' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
   2.jquery.js:4 POST https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSedlnzPGGIwjq_C3W0KCev-WexWs6SF-df7nk0sWT3v2wP6fA/formResponse net::ERR_FAILED
   I took reference of StackOverflow previous issues and placed below code also still it is not working

Js code:

```
$('.contact-us').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

              $.ajax({
                  url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSedlnzPGGIwjq_C3W0KCev-WexWs6SF-df7nk0sWT3v2wP6fA/formResponse",
                  data:$('form').serialize(),
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "xml",
                  crossDomain: true,
                  success: function(data){
                    //window.location.replace("youraddress");
                    alert("asdsad");
                  },
                  error: function(data){
                    //console.log(data);
                  }
              });
          });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSedlnzPGGIwjq_C3W0KCev-WexWs6SF-df7nk0sWT3v2wP6fA/formResponse"
       method="post" class="comment-form contact-form" id="mG61Hd" >
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="entry.2005620554">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Mail Address"  name="entry.1045781291">
        <textarea name="entry.839337160"  class="form-control" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="contact-us thm-btn"><span>Post Now</span></button>
</form>

</div>
```

Kindly let me know how to post form sucessfully.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a form in your website that you want, when submitted, to populate the Google Form? Why do you want to do that? Why don't you just embed the Google Form in your website?

Comment: The data still gets posted to the google sheets linked to the form. I am facing the same issue.